# Trying to setup Roundcube using iRedmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email-server, roundcube, webmail

I'm trying to setup Roundcube using iRedmail.

iRedAdmin works fine - I am able to create domains and users without issue.

However, when I am trying to log on with a newly created email address in the Roundcube client, I am getting the following error:

```
Connection to storage server failed.
```

I decide to check out the `/var/log/mail.log`, and I found the following error at the bottom:

```
Nov  7 01:28:42 hostname roundcube: IMAP Error: Login failed for myemail@mydomainname.com from 98.250.250.230. LOGIN: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. in /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail-1.0.1/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184(POST/mail/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)
```

I am struggling to understand what the exact problem is - as far as I can tell, Roundcube/iRed is having trouble talking to my IMAP service? (Dovecot, I believe?).

This is using Postfix and Dovecot.

How can I fix this? I want to have mail for multiple virtual hosts, and I feel like I'm super close, but there's some sort of configuration I'm missing.

One thing I did note was that my `/etc/apache2/conf.d/iredadmin.conf` file had the following line that I had to either comment out or change or else Apache wouldn't load:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess iredadminnew user=iredadmin threads=15
```

I change the process name from `iredadmin`, to `iredadminnew`.

Not sure if that's relevant.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

This is on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Do you have the php5-imap package installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes, this is installed and enabled. At least as far as I can tell. It is definitely installed, and when I look at a list of PHP modules, it says imap among the rest of the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Amavis had a configuration setting that was incorrect. I fixed this, started the service and it allows me to login.

I can now send email (sorta) but can't receive it, but I'll make a new question about that.